# Jump to a particular place in a webpage

Tags: html

I have links like this:

```
 <a class="faq_text_header_jump" href="#general_questions">General Questions</a><br>
  <a class="faq_text_header_jump" href="#how">How do i..</a><br>
  <a class="faq_text_header_jump" href="#once_you_book">Once you've booked lessons..</a>
```

And a target like so:

```
<div class="faq_text_section_header" id="how"><h2>How do I...?</h2></div>
```

But my 2nd and 3rd links don't work.

See an example here: http://lessonshark.com/dev1/homes/faq

Answer (score 7):

HTML has a solution for that.

use

```
<a name="target">
```

to mark the position in the page you want to jump to

```
<a href="page.html#target">
```

Comment: I had it like that to...and it wasn't quite working only the first one

Answer (score 1):

Use the `id` attribute to specify the destination of the link. This is the recommended practice, though the older `<a name=...>...</a>` works too, though it is more limited. What you *must not* do under any circumstances is to specify the destination twice using the same name. Currently the markup has

```
<a name="how_do_i">
    <div class="faq_text_section_header" id="how_do_i" >How do I...?</div></a>
```

This is invalid as per HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 (though permitted in HTML5 drafts), since an `a` element must not contain a `div` element. More seriously, this makes how_do_i doubly defined, which can cause just about anything. Fix this to just

```
<div class="faq_text_section_header" id="how_do_i" >How do I...?</div>
```

and make sure that your link uses `href="#how_do_i"` (as it does now, but the question said otherwise). Consider making that `div` an `h2` (and tune the stylesheet accordingly), since it’s really a heading.

Also note that in the link,

```
<a class="faq_text_header_jump"href="#how_do_i">How do i..</a>
```

there should be a space before `href`. This is just formal syntax, but it is best to get it right so that you can utilize a validator efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You need a named anchor somewhere in your document.

To create a named anchor, just use HTML like this:

```
<a name="anynameyoulike"></a>
```

Then, you can jump back to that point in the page with a link like this one:

```
<a href="#anynameyoulike">Jump to Named Anchor</a>
```